# how to check whether one instance of shell script is already running - Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have two different shell script say like

```
a.sh 
b.sh

**code of a.sh**

#!/system/bin/sh
#some code
./xyz/b.sh &
```

Here we can see i am running `b.sh` through `a.sh file` which is postboot script. Each time when device gets reboot it is adding `./xyz/b.sh` & which i am trying to avoid.

```
what i am trying to do : 
i need to write a code in such a way that will find if ./system/xyz/b.sh & is already there then no need to add again.



Code : 
if  pgrep /xyz/b.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
then
echo aplog is running
exit 1
fi
```

these code is not running. Do not know where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
pgrep b.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ 0 == $? ]
then
...
fi
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a code only answer is not high quality.  It would be better to describe what the code does and why you chose this approach.   It would also be nice to provide links to relevant documentation.

Comment: @user3728877 there is process id for b.sh then how will i use pgrep

Answer (score 0):

pgrep will only work on process name, not full path to process name.

Try pgrep -f b.sh or pgrep -x b.sh instead of pgrep -x /xyz/b.sh

Answer (score -1):

Hi test your file existence before creating it with:

```
filename="/fullpath/xyz/b.sh"
if [ -f "$filename" ]
then
        echo "$filename found"
else
        echo "$filename not found."
fi
```

Comment: I think that OP wants to check for the existence of the process, not the script file.